# Custom AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-alertdialog, dialogfragment

I'm trying to create **Custom AlertDialog** that gives me the full details of an item in listview when it clicks, but when I inflate the layout it won't give me proper measurements of the layouts I have created here's what I mean:

[image: how I want it to be seen:]

[image: how it appear with onCreateDialog]

[image: Listener]

[image: Sizes of layouts in the XML code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For inflating your dialog to the full view you must add this code to the **onActivityCreated()** or can be done it **onCreate Dialog()** but after dialog creation. So it is would be efficient to use this in **onActivityCreated()** method

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    return dialog;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(getLayoutId(), container, false);
}



@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Hoe this will help you.

Comment: tried both ways still the same problem, i think the problem is that i doesn't inflate the view with the proper measurements

Comment: I have edited my answer and add full code to the dialog fragment. Hope this will help you and if not helping then add a frame layout with match parent attributes to your XML code root and then retry it.

Comment: Still not working where do you want me to put framelayour in my custom xml file or the xml of the activity

Comment: in your dialog fragment put frame layout as root layout